# Orocommerce Adding a custom entity field and making it required on form

Tags: orocommerce

I'm trying to add a phone input to the registration page in Orocommerce.  I've update the back office entity for Customer User and added a phone field.  I am able to see it in the registration page in the storefront.  I want to make this field required.  I've added a symfony form extension with the following below.

```
<?php
namespace <custom>\Bundle\CustomerBundle\Form\Extension;

use Oro\Bundle\CustomerBundle\Form\Type\FrontendCustomerUserRegistrationType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractTypeExtension;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\NotBlank;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvent;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvents;

class FrontendCustomerUserRegistrationTypeExtension extends AbstractTypeExtension
{
    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $field = $builder->get('phone');
        $options = $field->getOptions();
        $options['required'] = true;
        $options['attr'] = ['placeholder' => '+X(XXX)XXX-XXX'];
        $options['constraints'] = array_merge($options['constraints'], [new NotBlank()]);
 
        $builder->add(
            $field->getName(),
            TextType::class,
            $options
        );
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function getExtendedType()
    {
        return FrontendCustomerUserRegistrationType::class;
    }
}
```

When I reload the registration page after this code change.  I get the following error:

The child with the name "phone" does not exist.

Is there something else I need to add to be able to call $builder->get('phone')?  If I try to update another default field, for example email $builder->get('email').  I get no errors and I am able to make option changes to it, such as changing the placeholder, required, etc.

Edit:
If I bypass the get() and do an add() I get this error:

"Extend field "phone" cannot be added to the form. A field with the same name already exists or was added by other extensions."

```
   public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
   {
        $builder->add('phone', TextType::class, ['mapped' => false, 'required' => true]);
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

These are the following steps to add a field to the registration page and set required with a placeholder.

1. Add schema file for the field.  Make note of the option 'form' => ['is_enabled' => false].  By setting it false, it will allow you to add it manually with buildForm.

src\YourCompany\Bundle\CustomerBundle\Migrations\Schema\v1_0

```
<?php
namespace YourCompany\Bundle\CustomerBundle\Migrations\Schema\v1_0;

use Doctrine\DBAL\Schema\Schema;
use Oro\Bundle\EntityExtendBundle\EntityConfig\ExtendScope;
use Oro\Bundle\MigrationBundle\Migration\Migration;
use Oro\Bundle\MigrationBundle\Migration\QueryBag;

/**
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.TooManyMethods)
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveClassLength)
 */
class AddAddress implements Migration
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function up(Schema $schema, QueryBag $queries)
    {
        $table = $schema->getTable('oro_customer_user');

        $table->addColumn('phone', 'string',
            [
                'oro_options' => [
                    'extend' => [
                        'is_extend' => true,
                        'owner' => ExtendScope::OWNER_CUSTOM
                    ],
                    'form' => ['is_enabled' => false],
                    'view' => ['is_displayable' => true],
                    'entity' => ['label' => 'Phone Number']
                ]
            ]
        );
    }
}
```

2. Add form type extension.

src\YourCompany\Bundle\CustomerBundle\Form\Extension\FrontendCustomerUserRegistrationTypeExtension.php

```
<?php
namespace YourCompany\Bundle\CustomerBundle\Form\Extension;

use Oro\Bundle\CustomerBundle\Form\Type\FrontendCustomerUserRegistrationType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractTypeExtension;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\NotBlank;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvent;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvents;

class FrontendCustomerUserRegistrationTypeExtension extends AbstractTypeExtension
{
    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
      $builder->add('country', CountryType::class, [
          'required' => true,
          'label' => 'Country',
          'attr' => ['placeholder' => '+X(XXX)XXX-XXXX']
      ])
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function getExtendedType()
    {
        return FrontendCustomerUserRegistrationType::class;
    }
}
```

Alternatively if all you need is to make a field required without any other options like placeholder, you can just create a validation.yml file and add the field to the entity in the backoffice without having to do a type extension.

src\YourCompany\Bundle\CustomerBundle\Resources\config\validation.yml

```
Oro\Bundle\CustomerBundle\Entity\CustomerUser:
    properties:
        phone:
            - NotBlank: ~
```